# MongoDB replica creation error: Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy MongoDB replica set. I have made my MongoDB instance as primary of the replica in First Digitalocen droplet. Now I am trying to add another MongoDB instance hosted on Second Digitalocen droplet, as secondary of the replica. I have also open 27017 port in the firewall(ufw) with allowing IP address `27017 ALLOW Anywhere  27017 ALLOW 206.189.168.245`

but I am getting the following error:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add('206.189.168.245:27017')
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: 159.89.150.245:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 206.189.168.245:27017 failed with Couldn't get a connection within the time limit",
    "code" : 74,
    "codeName" : "NodeNotFound" 
}
```

Here, Digitalocean droplet version: Ubuntu 16.04.4 x64 and MongoDB version: v3.4.16

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling **SELinux** and **Firewalld**.

To check SELinux and Firewalld status:

1. **sestatus**
2. **systemctl status firewalld**

It will work...